# Use Vue.js plugin in Vuex Store module

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to use a Vue.js plugin inside of a Vuex Store module.

In a *component*, I am able to call it like this: `this.$plugin()`. However, in a *module*, `this` is not set. I thought `Vue.$plugin()` would work since I initialize the plugin with `Vue.use(plugin)` and *Vue* being a global variable, but it doesn't.

How do I reference the plugin from a module?

Comment: Is it your plugin? Do you have the code?

Comment: Here is the plugin: https://github.com/euvl/vue-notification

Trying to use `this.$notify()`. But this should apply to all plugins with instance methods.

Comment: Using `this` is definitely not going to work, Vuex is not an instance of Vue. Looking over the plugin it doesn't look like it gives you an easy way to do what you want.

Comment: Here's a [hacky way](https://codesandbox.io/s/jp4xmzl0xy) you might do this. But I think you would probably want to create a notifications array in Vuex state, and populate it when a notification is necessary, then in Vue watch the notifications queue and pop/display them as needed.

Comment: Thats pretty much how I ended up doing. `window._app = new Vue({});` and `_app.$notify({});`

Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered by [Bert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38065/bert) in the example provided here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jp4xmzl0xy

```js
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import App from './App'
    import Notifications from 'vue-notification'
    import Vuex from "vuex"
    Vue.use(Notifications)
    Vue.use(Vuex)
    
    let notifier = new Vue()
    
    
    const store = new Vuex.Store({
      state:{},
      actions:{
        notify(context, payload){
          notifier.$notify(payload)
        }
      }
    })
    
    
    /* eslint-disable no-new */
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      store,
      template: '<App/>',
      components: { App }
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way I found is to import Vue in the store/module and then use the plugin via the Vue prototype.

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

// .. in some logic
Vue.prototype.$dialog.alert('Something went wrong');
```

Comment: This is working, thanks. I was just wondering: don't we create a sort of "double import": vue imports the module and the module imports vue?

Comment: @massimoi, I don't believe so. Circular imports would cause many issues, but it is common in Vue to import it in order to register plugins or use it's extended features.

Answer (score 1):

## Pass in the vue instance as an argument

Another option is to pass the vue instance as an argument for your action.

```
// Vue component
{
  methods: {
    const vm = this
    this.$store.dispatch('someaction', { vm })
  }
}

// Store action
{
  someaction (context, { vm }) {
    vm.$dialog.alert('Something went wrong')
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the best way to go. Are there caveats to this method like building for production or anything?

Comment: @rgin There is no caveat besides the fact that you are passing in to vuex an instance of vue which is not ideal since it makes your code harder to maintain. Building this for production will work.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, ended up having to refactor the code because of this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of other ways I've found. Honestly not sure which is the best though. I really don't like importing Vue and calling prototype methods. Seems like a complete antipattern and particularly difficult when it comes to testing using localVue as the actions have been coupled to global Vue.

1. I'm pretty sure you're not *supposed* to do this but you can access the vue instance of the store from within an action using `this._vm.$notify`
2. You can create a store plugin:

```js
const notifyStore = (store) => {
  store.$notify = store._vm.$notify
}
```

3. Create notify as a standalone module

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

let notifier = new Vue()

export default notifier
```

4. A combination of the two

```js
import notifier from './notifier'

const notifyStorePlugin = (store) => {
  store.$notify = notifier.$notify
}
```

I'm not saying this is *the* definitive answer on this. I'm also very open to feedback and other suggestions.